# Чтение данных из файла SWI-Prolog

Tags: файлы, swi-prolog

Есть файл с каким-то текстом. Надо вывести на экран всё его содержимое.

Проблема заключается в переходе на новую строку. У меня читается лишь первая, на этом всё. 

 
Попробовал использовать **repeat**, однако теперь всё зациклилось. 

Код:

```
    main:-
        File = '/home/timur/temp.txt',
        see(File),
        repeat,
        readln(T),
%        write(T),
        print(T),
        T = end_of_file, !, seen.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
readFromFile(File):-
    open(File,read,Stream),
    get_char(Stream,Char1),
    process_the_stream(Char1,Stream),
    close(Stream).

% Exit condition
process_the_stream(end_of_file,_):-
    !.

process_the_stream(Char,Stream):-
    print(Char),
    get_char(Stream,Char2),
    process_the_stream(Char2,Stream).


main:-
    FilePath = '/home/timur/src.txt',
    readFromFile(FilePath).
```

Как делать через функции, описанные в шапке - не знаю.